# Axios get request gives response after page refresh in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have the following code in agent.vue file. I am fetching the agent by axios get request. But the issue I am facing here is that get request doesn't work the first time. I have to refresh the page to get the agent. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

```
<template>
 <p>{{agent.fname}}</p>
 <p>{{agent.lname}}</p>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      agent: {
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
      }, 
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchAgent();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchAgent() {
      this.$axios.get('/organisation/agent.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.agent = response.data;
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try mounted hook instead of created

Comment: @fullmetal I tried it. still the same issue

Comment: should only have one element in template

Answer (score 2):

It makes sens to trigger API calls to fetch data in the `created()` life cycle hook.

Apart from what @Lawrence Cherone said, your code should work. I feel you did not replicate your real issue. Otherwise, please try:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="agent.fname"> {{ agent.fname }} </p>
    <p v-if="agent.lname"> {{ agent.lname }} </p>
  </div>
</template>
```